# How to find whether the Redis cache is Up or Not in NodeJS before calling client.get()

Tags: node.js, redis

In Our node Rest API application, we are using Redis cache for caching some data. We need to give a system error for the API request if the Redis server is down. Please suggest a solution for resolving this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'client.on' function to check if redis server is up or not.
Example use:

```
var Redis = require('ioredis');


var client = new Redis({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 6379,
});

client.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error('Redis Server is not up')
 })
```

I brought my redis-server down and got the following console log as expected:

```
Redis Server is not up
```

You can handle the logic inside the callback for redis.on function.

Comment: If the Redis server is down how we give the replay system error . The above code does not handle that one

Comment: How we can check when the Redis server is down in API call and need to give a suitable response to our API

Comment: The answer that  I have written does that for you. I brought down my redis-server and got the console log "Redis Server is not up".

Comment: This answer also gets me in my sample also. client. on is an event rt? But when it comes to API requests I am not able to check whether the Redis server is down or not?

Comment: Can’t you add client.on to your API logic?